# What does %s mean in a Python format string?

Tags: python, string-formatting

What does `%s` mean in Python? And what does the following bit of code do?

For instance...

```
 if len(sys.argv) < 2:
     sys.exit('Usage: %s database-name' % sys.argv[0])

 if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
     sys.exit('ERROR: Database %s was not found!' % sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: The `%` operator is deprecated in favor of the more powerful `str.format` method, see [PEP-3101](http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101).

Comment: Actually that PEP says "In Python 3.0, the % operator is supplemented by a more powerful string formatting method" and that it is backported to Python 2.6. Where I come from "supplemented" means added to, not replaced. The PEP does not say "supplanted" and in no part of the PEP does it say the % operator is deprecated (yet it does say other things are deprecated down the bottom). You might prefer str.format and that's fine, but until there's a PEP saying it is deprecated there's no sense in claiming it is when it isn't.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

It is a string formatting syntax (which it borrows from C).

Please see ["PyFormat"](https://pyformat.info/):

> Python supports formatting values into
> strings. Although this can include
> very complicated expressions, the most
> basic usage is to insert values into a
> string with the `%s` placeholder.

Here is a really simple example:

```
#Python 2
name = raw_input("who are you? ")
print "hello %s" % (name,)

#Python 3+
name = input("who are you? ")
print("hello %s" % (name,))
```

The `%s` token allows me to insert (and potentially format) a string.  Notice that the `%s` token is replaced by whatever I pass to the string after the `%` symbol.  Notice also that I am using a tuple here as well (when you only have one string using a tuple is optional) to illustrate that multiple strings can be inserted and formatted in one statement.

Comment: Note that this kind of string interpolation is deprecated in favor of the more powerful `str.format` method.

Comment: In python3 raw_input() is now just input() for those of you who are trying for yourself.

Comment: Lol. @PauloScardine More powerful? formatted strings: `f'{}'` enters the chat.

Answer (score 153):

[Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-a-python-format-string/997807#997807) is good.

And just to help you out a bit more, here's how you use multiple formatting in one string:

```
"Hello %s, my name is %s" % ('john', 'mike') # Hello john, my name is mike".
```

If you are using ints instead of string, use %d instead of %s.

```
"My name is %s and I'm %d" % ('john', 12) #My name is john and I'm 12
```

Comment: nice.  %d saves you from casting str(int).  any idea what the %s and %d stand for?  i guess i'll remember them as string and digit.

Comment: @user391339  stands for decimal :)  they're all here https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Comment: I don't know for earlier versions, but at least for 3.6 it works the same even if you use `%s` on integers, it will just be converted into a string.

Comment: @lapin you are correct :) . but that may not always be what you want. Say you want to pad a digit, for example. `print('This number will be padded with 4 zeros: %05d ' % 1)` - this will work. `print('This number will be padded with 4 zeros: %05s ' % 1)` - this won't
`

Comment: @sqram Hi, Is there a way to change the position of John and mike without changing the position of john and mike in input?

Answer (score 36):

The `format` method was introduced in Python 2.6.  It is more capable and not much more difficult to use:

```
>>> "Hello {}, my name is {}".format('john', 'mike')
'Hello john, my name is mike'.

>>> "{1}, {0}".format('world', 'Hello')
'Hello, world'

>>> "{greeting}, {}".format('world', greeting='Hello')
'Hello, world'

>>> '%s' % name
"{'s1': 'hello', 's2': 'sibal'}"
>>> '%s' %name['s1']
'hello'
```

Comment: This answer would be improved if it explained that the syntax in the question was formatting text and _then_ demonstrated the newer method. That way it could stand on its own. Providing an example that was equivalent to the example in the question would also be a plus.

Answer (score 29):

`%s`and `%d` are *format specifiers* or placeholders for formatting strings, decimals, floats, etc.

The *most* common used *format specifiers*:

`%s`: string

`%d`: decimals

`%f`: float

Self explanatory code:

```
name = "Gandalf"
extendedName = "the Grey"
age = 84
IQ = 149.9
print('type(name): ', type(name)) # type(name): <class 'str'>
print('type(age): ', type(age))   # type(age): <class 'int'>
print('type(IQ): ', type(IQ))     # type(IQ): <class 'float'>

print('%s %s\'s age is %d with incredible IQ of %f ' %(name, extendedName, age, IQ)) # Gandalf the Grey's age is 84 with incredible IQ of 149.900000

# The same output can be printed in following ways:


print ('{0} {1}\'s age is {2} with incredible IQ of {3} '.format(name, extendedName, age, IQ))          # With the help of an older method
print ('{} {}\'s age is {} with incredible IQ of {} '.format(name, extendedName, age, IQ))          # With the help of an older method

print("Multiplication of %d and %f is %f" %(age, IQ, age*IQ)) # Multiplication of 84 and 149.900000 is 12591.600000

# Storing formattings in a string

sub1 = "python string!"
sub2 = "an arg"

a = "I am a %s" % sub1
b = "I am a {0}".format(sub1)

c = "with %(kwarg)s!" % {'kwarg':sub2}
d = "with {kwarg}!".format(kwarg=sub2)

print(a)  # "I am a python string!"
print(b)  # "I am a python string!"
print(c)  # "with an arg!"
print(d)  # "with an arg!"
```

Answer (score 14):

`%s` indicates a conversion type of *string* when using Python's string formatting capabilities. More specifically, `%s` converts a specified value to a string using the `str()` function. Compare this with the `%r` conversion type that uses the `repr()` function for value conversion.

Take a look at the [documentation for string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Answer (score 7):

To answer your second question:  What does this code do?...

This is fairly standard error-checking code for a Python script that accepts command-line arguments.

So the first `if` statement translates to:  if you haven't passed me an argument, I'm going to tell you how you should pass me an argument in the future, e.g. you'll see this on-screen:

```
Usage: myscript.py database-name
```

The next `if` statement checks to see if the 'database-name' you passed to the script actually exists on the filesystem.  If not, you'll get a message like this:

> ERROR: Database database-name was not found!

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> argv[0] is the script name (it is
> operating system dependent whether
> this is a full pathname or not). If
> the command was executed using the -c
> command line option to the
> interpreter, argv[0] is set to the
> string '-c'. If no script name was
> passed to the Python interpreter,
> argv[0] is the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good example in Python 3.

```
>>> a = input("What is your name? ")
What is your name? Peter

>>> b = input("Where are you from? ")
Where are you from? DE

>>> print("So you are %s of %s." % (a, b))
So you are Peter of DE.
```

Answer (score -1):

As the other answers rightfully mentioned: The `%s` operator is used in string formatting.

Although as from Python 3.6 and above, a more intuitive string formatting syntax is introduced, called the `f-string`.

[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

```py
full_name = 'Foo Bar'
print(f'My name is {full_name}')

# Output: My name is Foo Bar
```