# How to save links automatically repeat?

Tags: for-loop

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib import urlopen

import re

b = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.apache.org")

soup = BeautifulSoup(b)

for link in soup.findAll('a'):

print " %s link.get" % ('href')

f = open("/home/apache/test/test.txt", "w")

```
    f.write()

    f.close()
```

How to save links automatically repeat??????

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does %s mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

It's a placeholder for formatting. It represents a string.

```
" %s link.get" % ('href')
```

is equivalent to

```
" " + 'href' + " link.get"
```

The placeholders can make things more readable, without cluttering the text with quotes and +. Though in this case, there is no variable, so it is simply

```
" href link.get"
```

However, `.format()` is preferred to `%` formatting nowadays, like

```
" {} link.get".format('href')
```

Comment: How to save links automatically repeat?