# How to save a dictionary to a file with key values one per line?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want the text to be one key:count per line.
Right now it saves the file just as a plain dictionary and I can't figure it out.

```
def makeFile(textSorted, newFile) :
dictionary = {}
counts = {}
for word in textSorted :
    dictionary[word] = counts
    counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1

# Save it to a file
with open(newFile, "w") as file :
    file.write(str(counts))
file.close()
return counts
```

Comment: Do you want all key:count in different lines ?

Comment: Yes! One key:count per line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can so this is a couple of lines with a CounterDict and the csv module:

```
import csv
def makeFile(textSorted, newFile) :
    from collections import Counter
    with open(newFile, "w") as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter=":")
        wr.writerows(Counter(textSorted).items())
```

Using two dictionaries is pointless if you just want to store the key/value pairs. A single Counter dict will get the count for all the words and csv.writerows will write each pair separated by a colon one pairing per line.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
def makeFile(textSorted, newFile) :
    counts = {}
    for word in textSorted :
        counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1

    # Save it to a file
    with open(newFile, "w") as file :
        for key,value in counts.items():
            file.write("%s:%s\n" % (key,value))
    return counts
```

EDIT: since iteritems is removed from python 3, change code to items()

Comment: I got this error - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: are you using python 3?

Comment: use items() instead of iteritems() for python3
iteritems was removed in python3 and items does the same thing as iteritems did in python2

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! Could you also explain the %s part to me please? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: basically it is for string formatting, if I have a string and a number that i want in the string, I can do it like "%s for string and %d in number" % (string1, num) which string1 will replace %s and num will replace %d
you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-python
and

Comment: Although  ``"%s:%s\n" % (key,value)`` is not incorrect, I'd recommend replacing with ``"{}:{}\n".format(key, value)``.

Comment: I was a bit unaware of this, could you please explain the benefit of using it?

Comment: @NamitSingal There are plenty of articles about it, but here's a pretty good [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format) I found. In general, ``str.format()`` allows you to perform much more sophisticated formatting operations. Here's the [PEP describing the change](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Comment: The point of using `with` is you don't need to close the file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Did not notice the file.close() in the code, Just changed the loop, editted the answer. thanks,

Answer (score 2):

// Very basic dictionary to file printer

```
dictionary = {"first": "Hello", "second": "World!"}

with open("file_name.txt", "w") as file:

  for k, v in dictionary.items():

    dictionary_content = k + ": " + v + "\n"

    file.write(dictionary_content)
```

Comment: This overwrites dictionary_content each loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = open('a_file.txt','w')
x.write('\n'.join(str(your_dict).split(', ')))
x.close()
```