# Explicit str() conversion needed for old-style string formatting?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I'm maintaining an old Python codebase that has some very strange idioms scattered throughout it. One thing I've come across is string formatting using the percent-encoded style:

```
'Error %s: %s' % (str(err), str(message))
```

Ignoring the existence of `.format()` for modern string interpolation, the question I have is:

**Is it necessary to explicitly convert `%s` parameters with `str()` or is that exactly what `%s` does?**

Comment: Why don't you try `print '%s' % 1` and see?

Comment: I did and it worked. I even checked with a dummy class to see if the `__str__` method was called but I wanted to check whether that was default behaviour or part of a fall-back chain.

Comment: Ah, I see; note that it's helpful to mention that kind of thing in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no need for the explicit `str()` calls, the `%s` formatter *includes* a `str()` call already:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "I am a string for Foo"
... 
>>> '%s' % Foo()
'I am a string for Foo'
```

This is also explicitly documented in the [*String Formatting Operations* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

> `'s'`
>   String (converts any Python object using `str()`).

Comment: Thank you. I had struggled to find that part in the documentation when I looked.

Answer (score 2):

No need to do that. The `%s` is a string formatting syntax used for printing. This might help add some more context:

[What does %s mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact specification you use. The old style formatting using a syntax close to that of C lanuage's [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf). For instance,

- %s shows a string (invokes `str()` on the passed argument).
- %r shows a representation (invokes `repr()` on the passed argument).
- %d takes a number.
- etc.

You have the whole list on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Comment: The wording for `%s` was not ideal, I fixed it. But I explained python would call `str` on it. For the number however, python will only take an integer, you can check it easily: `"%d" % "42"` will raise an exception.