# How to convert a select query into a pandas DataFrame using PeeWee

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, peewee

Using the PeeWee ORM I have the following query:

```
query = DataModel.select()where(DataModel.field == "value")
```

Is there any way to convert `query` into a pandas DataFrame without iterating over all the values? I'm looking for a more "Pythonic" way of doing this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Assuming `query` is of type `peewee.SelectQuery`, you could do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(query.dicts()))
```

**EDIT:** As Nicola points out below, you're now able to do `pd.DataFrame(query.dicts())` directly.

Comment: Brilliantly simple, and works like a charm! I won't tell you how long I spent trying to figure that one out, it's embarrassing. lol

Comment: for some reason `list(query.dicts())` is failing if there is a column that has the name of the table... has anybody experienced the same issue?

Comment: Don't use list(), the correct code is: `pd.DataFrame(query.dicts())`

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone finds this useful, I was searching for the same conversion but in *Python 3*. Inspired by [@toto_tico's previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255157), this is what I came up with:

```py
import pandas
import peewee


def data_frame_from_peewee_query(query: peewee.Query) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    connection = query._database.connection()  # noqa
    sql, params = query.sql()
    return pandas.read_sql_query(sql, connection, params=params)
```

Checked with *Python 3.9.6*, `pandas==1.3.2` and `peewee==3.14.4`, using `peewee.SqliteDatabase`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing this out — this is 100% the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

The following is a ***more efficient way***, because it avoids creating the list and then pass it to the pandas dataframe. It also has the side benefit of ***preserving the order of the columns***:

```
df = pd.read_sql(query.sql()[0], database.connection())
```

You need direct access to the peewee `database`, for example, in the [quickstart tutorial](https://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html) corresponds to:

```
db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')
```

Of course, you can also create your own connection to the database.

***Drawback:*** you should be careful if you have repeated columns in the two tables, e.g. `id` columns would appear twice. So make sure to correct those before continuing.

---

If you are **using a peewee proxy**

```
import peewee as pw; 
database_proxy = pw.Proxy()
```

then the connection is here:

```
database_proxy.obj.connection()
```

Comment: How do you deal with the fact that `query.sql()[0]` returns a string with `%s` as placeholders?

Comment: I would have to take a look at your exact query but in generally it could mean that there is a format-string python syntax, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-a-python-format-string)

Comment: @LivingSilver94 It isn't a complete solution but getting a cursor and using mogrify works for postgres: `cursor = db.cursor()` then `pd.read_sql(cursor.mogrify(*query.sql()), ...)`