# Assign a value to the variable and use it inside another variable in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I want something like we use in shell

*new_folder = nice*

folder1= /opt/$new_folder/nnn

I tried to concatenate and also used % but it doesn't work.

Can someone please help?

Regards,
B

Comment: How do you mean does not work?

Comment: You should show the exact code you used when you "tried to concatenate and also used %", and the actual error you got rather than "it doesn't work".

Comment: %s works here for sure!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Python equivalent to Ruby's string interpolation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450592/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-rubys-string-interpolation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like here in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-python/998157#998157) explained:

> "Hello %s, my name is %s" % ('john', 'mike') # Hello john, my name is mike".

So for you:

```
new_folder = "nice"
folder1= "/opt/%s/nnn" % (new_folder)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MrZed . It worked.. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
new_folder = "nice"
folder1 = "/opt/{}/nnn".format(new_folder)
# or 
folder1 = "/opt/" + new_folder + "/nnn"
```

Comment: You can check some of the examples: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: Thank you so much  @thomas kowalski