# Regarding the string format in python, what does '[%s]' mean?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I saw a line of code:

```
re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
```

But I have no idea about the function of `[%s]`

Could anyone help me please?

Thank You!

Comment: this is something that has been talked about before. Try looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format) and see if you can find what you are looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does %s mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-python)

Comment: It means it's a really good idea to [read the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is a string formatting syntax (which it borrows from C).

Example:

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hello %s, nice to meet you!" % name)
```

And this is what the program will look like:

```
What is your name? Johnny
Hello Johnny, nice to meet you!
```

You can also do this with string concentation...

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hello + name + ", nice to meet you!")
```

...However, the formatting is usually easier.
You can also use this with *multiple* strings.

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
age = input("How old are you? ")
gender = ("Are you a male or a female? ")
print("Is this correct?")
print("Your name is %s, you are %s years old, and you are %s." % name, age, gender)
```

Output:

```
What is your name? Johnny
How old are you? 37
Are you a male or a female? male
Is this correct?
Your name is Johnny, you are 37 years old, and you are male.
```

Now, please, before asking **any more** questions, **see if they exist!**