# How to create a Regex based on user input (Python)

Tags: python, regex, input

I am fairly new to Python, and I am learning about Regexes right now, which has been a bit of a challenge for me. My issue right now is I am working on a problem that is to create a function that is a Regex version of the strip() string method.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to convert a character that user inputs into a regex without listing out every possibility in the program with if statements. For instance:

```
def regexStrip(string, char):
    if char = 'a' or 'b' or 'c' etc...
        charRegex = re.compile(r'^[a-z]+')
```

This isn't my full program just a few lines to demonstrate what I'm talking about. I was wondering if anyone could help me in finding a more efficient way to convert user input into a Regex.

Comment: Can you please clarify what will be the user input in your example? Does the user provide a regex? If not what is the relation between user input and the resultant regex?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I am not sure I understand what your question exactly is. Anyway, regular expressions were invented precisely for writing complex conditions on strings in a concise way. While there are better ways to write the second line of your code, e.g. `if char in string.ascii_lowercase:` (provided you have issued `import string` earlier), this is, in general, not simple. Besides, that regex would not be matching the same as the `if` condition.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055600/strip-function-using-regex) to see if it answers your question

Comment: Yeah sorry, I apologize for being unclear, I am new to this. I am supposed to be creating a function that takes two arguments. The first one is a string, and the second one is a character that is to be stripped from the string. The function is supposed to do what the strip() string method does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use braces inside strings and the [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function to build the regular expression.

```
def regexStrip(string, char=' '):
    #Removes the characters at the beginning of the string
    striped_left = re.sub('^{}*'.format(char), '', string)
    #Removes the characters at the end of the string
    striped = re.sub('{}*$'.format(char), '', striped_left)
    return striped
```

The strip method in python allows to use multiples chars, for example you can do 'hello world'.strip('held') and it will return 'o wor'

To perform this, you can do :

```
def regexStrip(string, chars=' '):
    rgx_chars = '|'.join(chars)
    #Removes the characters at the beginning of the string
    striped_left = re.sub('^[{}]*'.format(rgx_chars), '', string)
    #Removes the characters at the end of the string
    striped = re.sub('[{}]*$'.format(rgx_chars), '', striped_left)
    return striped
```

If you want to use search matching instead of substitutions, you can do :

```
def regexStrip(string, chars=' '):
    rgx_chars = '|'.join(chars)
    striped_search = re.search('[^{0}].*[^{0}]'.format(rgx_chars), string)
    if striped_search :
        return striped_search.group()
    else:
        return ''
```