# Open all json files in a folder

Tags: python, json

I have a folder with hundreds of `.json` files.
How to open all these files at once?

I have tried:

```
for i in os.listdir('C:/Users/new'):
    if i.endswith('.json'):
        files.append(open(i).read)
But I got this error:
```

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: When you say "open them all at once", do you actually mean "read all their contents sequentially?

Comment: yes. i would like to read all the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is only the filename. you should give the full path to the program.

example: let first file be `stackoverflow.json`

you try to open with filename such as:

```
open('stackoverflow.json', 'r')
```

what you should do is:

```
open('C:/Users/new/stackoverflow.json', 'r')
```

so the code should do it:

```
files = []
base_path = 'C:/Users/new'
for i in os.listdir(base_path):
    if i.endswith('.json'):
        full_path = '%s/%s' % (base_path, i)
        files.append(open(full_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read())

   print("starting to print json documents...")
   for single_file in files:
      print(single_file)
   print("printing done")
```

EDIT: as @khelwood states, you should also replace `read` with `read()`.

Comment: Consider also [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Comment: @user9781180 that problem seems to be out of context. can you share the full code and example input file?

Comment: Sorry. I rerun and it came up with another problem. NameError: name 'files' is not defined

Comment: its okay. the error is there because you never declared a variable named `files`. check my answer, i edited the code.

Comment: I've tried the newest code, however i got the error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 876: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @user9781180 I updated the last line. can you try it this way?

Comment: I tried it. I just have to print(files) for my content to load right? however i got the error of : IOPub data rate exceeded.

Comment: @user9781180 can you elaborate? what do you want to do with the data? I update the answer with print statements if you want to print them and see on the terminal logs.

Comment: Hi! thankyou so much. It worked!

Comment: is it possible to explain the last line of the code on the 'encoding='utf-8'?

Comment: @user9781180 in default, python uses utf-8 encoding in order to encode strings, i thought that might be causing your unicode error. i wanted to make sure your configuration is set to default.

Comment: I see... last question. What about this line : full_path = '%s/%s' % (base_path, i)

Comment: first, I declare the string structure. that is shown by "%s/%s". the "%s" means that a string variable will come there. so, in the structure, i pointed out that I wanted two string variables with a slash (/) between them. after that, I put the strings I want in the right order, which are `base_path` and `i`.

Comment: for more info you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-python

Comment: Thank you! I'll read more on it.