# raise IOError("%s not found." % path) error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print the result of data but I am getting above error. I also used `np.genfromtxt` command but it didn't work. Can some one please guide me regarding this issue?

```
path="folder"
datafiles=os.listdir(path)

for df in datafiles:
    print df
    data=genfromtxt(df, delimiter=' ')
     print data
```

Comment: How are you setting a path, this is how %s should be used https://stackoverflow.com/a/998157/3254405

Comment: You do understand that the files found will be in `folder/`, right?

Comment: yes the files are  in the folder directory. I'm assigning the right path. But there is something wrong with genfromtxt commad.

Comment: when I print df it shows that check1.0 and check1.5 files are in the folder.