# How this code replace the %s in my filename with certain values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner of Python.

I am trying to create a text file with using %s (I saw the example from textbook, but I don't know what %s exactly means here:

```
quizFile=open('%scapitalsquiz.txt'%2018,'w')
quizFile.write('%s. capital of %s?\n'%(1, 'New York'))
quizFile.close()
```

the above code will give me a text file whose name is:
**2018capitalsquiz**

so the %s is repalced by %2018

Also in my content of the text file, I have: **1. capital of New York?**

so two %s are replaced correspondingly by 1 and New York, I just want to know what is exactly function here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does %s mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-python)

Comment: What's your question, your question is not clear

Comment: Also since it is tagged as python-3.x, `%s` is old, newer is `.format`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%s` is a string formatting syntax. `%s` token is replaced by whatever you pass to the string after the % symbol. It basically uses the `str()` method to utilise the string formatting.