# Rename files in subfolders by specific format in Python

Tags: python, filenames

I have a folder with lots of subfolders. Each of subfolders has different type of image files. I'm trying to rename those files by specific format. Data looks like this:

```
folder
        \ sub1\file0.jpg
        \ sub1\file1.jpg
        \ sub1\file2.png
        .
        .
        .
        \ sub2\xxx.png
        \ sub2\yyy.jpg
        \ sub2\zzz.png
        .
        .
        .
```

Desired output:

```
folder
        \ sub1\file-01.jpg
        \ sub1\file-02.jpg
        \ sub1\file-03.png
        .
        .
        .
        \ sub2\file-01.png
        \ sub2\file-02.jpg
        \ sub2\file-03.png
        .
        .
        .
```

By far, I have tried following code but it doesn't work out.

```
import os

dir_name = "D:/folder"     
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_name, topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]#file name no ext
        extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
        dir_name = os.path.basename(root)
        os.rename(root+"/"+file, root+"/"+"file"+"s%"+extension)
```

Comment: "It doesn't work [out]" may be an accurate description of what happens, but we need a bit more. Did you try to see what each step does by insterting `print` commands between each step with the intermediate results?

Comment: `os.rename(root+"/"+file, root+"/"+"file"+"s%"+extension)` `s%` are you sure you're not missing your index and the proper formatting?

Comment: you could have an increment counter for each type of extension, and reinitialize them for every new sub folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using `enumerate`.

**Demo:**

```
import os

dir_name = "D:/folder"      
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_name, topdown=False):
    for num, file in enumerate(files, 1):   #enumerate to get number
        src =  os.path.join(root, file)
        file_s = os.path.splitext(file)
        dest = os.path.join(root, "{0}-{1}.{2}".format(file_s[0], str(num).rjust(2, "0"), file_s[1]))   #Form destination file name
        os.rename(src, dest)   #Rename.
```

Comment: you can lose the `"{0}-{1}.{2}"` for just `"{}-{}.{}"`

Comment: be careful about `file.split(".")`. Files can contain several dots. That's why `os.path.splitext` exists.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry maybe i didn't explain very clearly. I have tried with your code. It renamed file sub1\file0.jpg to sub1\file0-01..jpg, sub2\xxx.png to sub2\xxx-01..png; which is slightly different to my desired output: sub1\file0.jpg to sub1\file-01.jpg, sub2\xxx.png to sub2\file-01.png.

Comment: `dest = os.path.join(root, "{}-{}.{}".format("file", str(num+100).rjust(2, "0"), file_s[1]))` ?

Comment: dest = os.path.join(root, "{}-{}.{}".format("file", str(num+00).rjust(2, "0"), file_s[1]))

Comment: The code above works, but it generates two points as follows: file-01..jpg

Comment: use `"{}-{}{}".`

Answer (score 1):

> `os.rename(root+"/"+file, root+"/"+"file"+"s%"+extension)`

You're using the `%s` string formatting syntax wrong (I'm assuming that's what you intend to do). Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-a-python-format-string). Just as a reminder, you need an actual variable to be inserted in place of `%s`. I'm sure you can figure out how to implement that. (the other answer gives a possible solution, too)

In fact, I'd suggest using string formatting for `root`, `file`, and `extension` as well - and while you're at that, consider using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) instead of the `%s` syntax.