# Python "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python

I am using Python and having trouble because of 'String formatting' error.

```
x = int(input())
x_list = ' '.join(str(x)).split()
for i in range(len(x_list)):
    if x_list[i] % 2 == 0  and x_list[i+1] % 2 == 0 :
        x_list.insert(i+1,'*')
```

x_list is an arbitrary list that I made, and the error occurs at the 4th line.
I think the error occurs because of the '%', which I wanted to use to calculate the remainder.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does x_list contain strings? Maybe Pyhon interprets the % sign as a directive to format string at `x_list[i] % 2`, in similar to this example `'Hello, %s' % name`.

Comment: Please post more context of your code.

Comment: I edited my code.

Comment: `x_list` is not an *arbitrary* list, it is a list of strings. Either convert the whole list back to ints, or just surround each get `int(x_list[i]) % 2`

Comment: use a debugger and see what the result of each line is. You make fundamental errors. and read the docs about all functions you use

Comment: `x_list[i]` is a string. So how do you imagine `x_list[i] % 2 == 0` working?

Comment: I changed x_list as 'x_list = list(map(int, ' '.join(str(x)).split()))', but the error keeps going on.

Comment: The same error? I don't think so... Probably an IndexError and that because it needs to be `for i in range(len(x_list)-1):` because you read 2 items each loop

Comment: @JongminLee Thats because you insert a string manually again into this int list, so the error will inevitably happen again, you need to use seperate lists.

Answer (score 1):

***Warning Note***

Modifying list while looping on it is not preferable.

***Some Explanation***

What happens is that the line `x_list[i] % 2` is interpreted as a directive to format string, as originally `x_list` contains strings.

Formatting with `%` is deprecated currently, on Python 3, however, you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-a-python-format-string).

***Mitigations***

Note: This solves the formatting error, other logical errors that related to functionality may still exist.

```
x = int('12234')
x_list = ' '.join(str(x)).split()
# Going from indices 0...(N-1) as we use (i+1) each iteration
for i in range(len(x_list)-1):
    # Validating current and next are not invalid char '*'
    if '*' in [x_list[i], x_list[i+1]]:
        continue
    if int(x_list[i])% 2 == 0  and int(x_list[i+1])% 2 == 0 :
        x_list.insert(i+1,'*')

# ['1', '2', '*', '2', '3', '4']
print(x_list)
```

Comment: Some clarification for the "don't modify list while you are looping it" in this case. If you have more than two even numbers in a row in the list, it will fail as it will then try and multiply * with a number.

Comment: Thank you @en_lorithai for the comment. Added clarification regarding the mitigations, it's just for the code not to raise formatting exception. There are logical flaws at the original code, therefore on code based on it.

Answer (score 1):

If your `x_list` contains strings then you quite obviously cannot calculate the remainder of that string divided by 2.

Also, even if your `x_list` only contains numbers, you could encounter an `IndexError`, since in your last iteration `x_list[i+1]` could be out of bounds.

You are also modifying the same list as you are looping over it, which is generally undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a string formatting issue because you're inserting a string '*' into the list you're iterating through already, at one index down from i. You can't have a string perform modulo operations. Not entirely sure what you are trying to do there, but what you're seeing is normal behavior.

Also, the way your code currently works, you won't reach all of the integers in your original list.

EDIT: Responding to your edit:

```
x_list = ' '.join(str(x)).split()
for i in range(len(x_list)):
    if x_list[i] != '*':
        if (int(x_list[i]) % 2 == 0)  and (int(x_list[i+1]) % 2 == 0):
            x_list.insert(i+1,'*')
```

Just change your strings to int and check if the value at i is '*' or not

Comment: You are right but the problem is even before the `*`. The initial list itself is consisted of strings representing numbers, not ints...

Answer (score 0):

The way you convert [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) into [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) of chars is not correct and can be easily replaced by [`list(string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). If you want to check all chars to be valid digits you can add [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal).

You're trying to modify list you're iterating over, which is also a mistake. Modifying source inside loop would break logic of loop, as a result some elements could be processed several times or skipped.

Finally you're trying to apply modulo *(which is [numeric](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) operation)* on `str`. To let it work as you expected you should cast element to `int` using [`int(string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Edited code:

```
x = input()
if x.isdecimal():
    x_list = list(x)
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(x_list) - 1):
        new_list.append(x_list[i])
        if not (int(x_list[i]) % 2 and int(x_list[i + 1]) % 2):
            new_list.append("*")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = input()
x_list = ' '.join(str(x)).split()
for i in range(len(x_list)):
    try:
        if not(int(x_list[i]) % 2 and int(x_list[i+1]) % 2):
            x_list.insert(i+1,'*')
    except:
        continue

print(x_list)
```

Try this, it may work.
idk what the output should be like "because you didn't mention it".
but i tried to type the same code with some changes to avoid the error

Comment: Have you tried to research what exactly cause an error?

Comment: @OlvinRoght what causes an error is two things, the first is when he tried to do "%2" on a string (num).
and the second error occur when he tried to do "%2" on the actual "string" operator, which is '*'.

Comment: So why have you decided to handle exception instead of preventing it?

Comment: @OlvinRoght The exception just to prevent the string operator '*', because even if i type an if statement it'll work but it would be something like `if x_list[i] != '*' and x_list[i+1] != '*'` which is not legal because it won't be true 'never', just try it.
I've try it already and it didn't work. EDIT: If you type an if statement like this `if x_list[i] != '*'` it'll give you an error, because inside the if statement he's using `x_list[i] and x_list[i+1]`, and ofc the `x_list[i+1]` will be `*` in a way or another.

Comment: Even if you add 2 additional conditions *(which is ofc possible)* it will be another way of handling exception. I wanted to point you that you're inserting item into a list which you're currently processing in same loop, that's the main mistake.